# How to set default timezone in angular project globally?

Tags: angular

I try to work with UTC date in my Angular project, not with the local date. I've seen in several posts that it's enough to use this:

```
moment.tz.setDefault(String);
```

I've searched a lot and I haven't found out how or where I can write this piece of code to make it work.

Does anyone have an idea how to use it?

Comment: you can use the provider in app.modul and set the timezone you want

Answer (score 0):

[Moment](https://momentjs.com/) is a great library for handling date issues. Almost everyone uses the same library and yes it's enough.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-moment

```
<script src="components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="components/moment/locale/de.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);

myapp.run(function(amMoment) {
  amMoment.changeLocale('de');
});
```

Comment: I think that this in AngularJs. I am locking for the emplacement of the code in angular 9. I know that we use this library (moment) both in AngulrJs and in Angular.

Comment: npm install moment --save \\\\
import * as moment from 'moment';

Comment: In Angular in which file we put this amMoment.changeLocale('de')

Comment: app.component.ts file.